# How to produce 100 with only four 3s and mathematical symbols

Tags: elementary-functions

An approach like this doesn't count!

$\underset{k \in \mathbb N, k \leq (3+3/3)} {\sum k^3}$

Thanks for your answers but I need something more strong... 
You are only allowed to use +, -, *, /, !, (, ), ^ and sqrt !

Comment: That's very clever!

Comment: Do you know the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no... :(

Answer (score 3):

$3 \times 33.\dot3{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It's interesting to note that, at this very point in time, the number of upvotes for this solution is 3 :)

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{33}{33\%} = \dfrac{33}{.33}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3):

$(\dfrac{ 3}{ .3})^\dfrac{3!}{3}$.

Comment: It's interesting to note that, at this very point in time, the number of upvotes for this solution is 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

$\lceil33\times3+\log3\rceil{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$